# Convert SQL to Entity Framework Linq convert to list C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am stuck at selecting a list of ID based on another list of ID in Entity Framework.

I googled and saw some examples but I am unable to find the answer I am looking for

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Main m 
INNER JOIN MainMapping cm ON mm.MainId = m.ID
WHERE mm.SecondId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

I am trying to convert this SQL to EF Linq.

Here is what I got so far:

```
var listOfId = await _context.Main
                      .Include(main => main.MainMapping)
                      .Where(main => main.MainMapping 
                          .Where(mapping => request.SecondIdList.Any(y => y == mapping.SecondId)))
                      .ToListAsync();
```

But I keep getting errors. What am I missing?

These are the errors:

> Error CS1662  Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Testing1.Domain.Entities.MainMapping>' to 'bool'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first, everytime you call `.Where` to filter something, you must return a `boolean` expression. Given you are using `Linq to SQL` your expression should return something that is possible to parse to `sql` language.

About your queston, you could try using `.Any` on your collection property to return a boolean and `Contains` to generate an `IN` statement. Then, to return a collection of `Id`, use `Select` to change the output. EF will parse it to valid sql expression.

```
var listOfId = await _context.Main
    .Include(main => main.MainMapping)
    .Where(main => main.MainMapping.Any(mapping => request.SecondIdList.Contains(mapping.SecondId)))    
    .Select(man => main.Id)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Oh i see i see
Thanks so much for ur help!!